# Measuring deviation in a music waveform in R?

Tags: r, image

I have posted this question in the R tag but I am open to solutions in other languages.

Lets say you have some waveforms. The first is just a bar. It is completely horizontal so it has no deviation. The other waveforms look like these:

[image]

Now I am able to get these waveforms separated into a uniform box so that they are all the same pixel size and resolution. My first idea was to quantify the amount of whitespace within one of these uniform boxes that the waveform used up using the code found here:
[Measuring whitespace in a jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670005/measuring-whitespace-in-a-jpeg)

Now however I want to measure the deviation between waveforms. That is, how could I quantify how "jumpy" a waveform is? Looking at the picture above, the second waveform seems the most homogeneous, and the third waveform seems to display the most variation, but I am unsure about how to quantify this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Maxwell, I could help you to actually analyze the sound in R, I think that would be way better, let me know if you think that is an alternative to the image processing

Comment: @Derek I am absolutely open to this as long as I can get some numerical measures for each waveform. Thanks!

Comment: I hope this answer helps, I would be happy to help more if you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend starting by getting familiarized with the packages [tuneR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneR/tuneR.pdf) and [seewave](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/seewave.pdf), you can [import](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/vignettes/seewave_IO.pdf) and extract a lot of parameters from these two packages. In particular you could use the function `acustat` from **seewave**, this is a worked example with data from the package

```
data(tico)
note <- cutw(tico, from=0.5, to=0.9, output="Wave")
a<-acoustat(note)
```

*a* will give you 10 acoustic parameters from the sound, you could also use other packages like soundecology, that also extract some other variables, in particular, the function `acoustic_diversity` measures sound complexity

Comment: This is just what I needed to kick this analysis up to the next level. Thanks!